# Resize image in PS CS6 without losing image quality?

Tags: image-quality, image-processing, resize, photoshop-cs6

I have a png logo file but i want to resize it without breaking the image. Can I have any tips ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about non-photo image editing. Could be redirected to Superuser or GraphicDesign.

Comment: "resize it without breaking the image" – What you want to do is generally not possible.

Comment: If you want to do this properly, the logo image should be a [_vector_ image](https://vectormagic.com/support/understanding_vector_images), not a _raster_ image. Essentially, a vector image is stored internally by describing points, lines, shapes, angles, colours, etc. Vector images can be resized to any size, and those internal relationships are maintained without any loss of quality. A raster image is stored as a grid of coloured pixels at a fixed size, and any resizing needs some interpolation (and quality loss) by definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there is only one good way to enlarge an image in Photoshop and thats with image->image-size and then choose a good algorithm and possibly try different ones as described [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/resizing-image.html).

The big problem with logos is that a lot of them are quite small and if you are trying to make them a lot bigger they will always loose in quality and break. You are always loosing quality when resizing.

From my experience this quality loss can be kept smaller when you are doing this not in 1  big step but in multiple smaller ones and correct the image whenever you see an error like the loss of a hard edge. When you are correcting the errors when the image is bigger it will be more work to make it look nice.

Most of it is at least for me trail and error and try to get the best result from it.